# How does Windows 8.1 detect whether a machine is a desktop or a tablet?

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, desktop-application, tablet

Windows 8.1 -- the full version, not RT -- automatically boots to the desktop when run from a desktop computer and to the Start screen when run from a tablet. (This functionality may require Update 1; I'm not sure.)

What information does Windows 8.1 use to make this decision, and can I access it programmatically from C++? I have an application that includes a driver that does not (currently) work properly on tablets, so I would like to use this information to warn the user at install time.

Comment: The Bing brings: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40675e27-9d61-419a-a0d7-50ec17faf02d/windows-81-tablet-detection?forum=w8itprogeneral which is a standard WMI query, so is eminently accessible from C++. Mind you I got 11 from my Surface Pro 2, which (?is) a tablet? I'm kind of confused now...

Comment: Ah, [the full list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156537.aspx) explains things a little better. 11 means *hand held*.

Comment: **That full list is amazing**.  I'm wondering what kind of voting flurry would occur if a stackoverflow question asked how to determine programmatically whether a sandwich might be found inside a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `GetSystemMetrics(SM_TABLETPC)` is sufficient for my needs, but the WMI query in the comments above is certainly useful if more granular information is needed.

Comment: I guess you weren't interested in the "What information does Windows 8.1 use to make this decision?" part of your question after all?

Comment: I am interested in that (and might still even accept an answer that explained it), but nobody seems to know and this solved my problem in the meantime.